# Spring Data JPA creates two tables after renaming entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.4 and Java 17. And I previously had an Entity called `BlogPostComment` but recently decided that just `Comment` is more concise. I don't have a data.sql file to explicitly create tables and let Hibernate handle all the database operations for me. So I'm expecting that the table previously named `blog_post_comment` would be renamed as `comment`. However, when I rerun my application after renaming the entity, Hibernate creates two tables `blog_post_comment` and `comment` instead of just the latter.

Before renaming:

```java
@Entity
public class BlogPostComment { ... }
```

After renaming:

```java
@Entity
public class Comment { ... }
```

I've tried adding `@Table(name = "comment")` annotation to this entity, but Hibernate created the table with the old name all the same. And I've also tried invalidating IntelliJ IDEA caches, still did not solve this problem. Please help me identify the cause of this error, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property in application.properties is set to **none** . What none does is that no action is performed. The schema will not be generated. Hence your changes will appear as a new table in your database. What you should do then is to set the property to **update** and then run the application. What update does is that the database schema will be updated by comparing the existing database schema with the entity mappings.

PS: If no property is defined, the default property is none. You should add the property and set to **update**

Comment: I didn't explicitly set this property previously. And I tried setting it to update, still not quite solving the problem.

Comment: The Entity annotation describes that your class in an entity which has a table mapped on the database and the @Table annotation is always used together with the previous annotation to properly name your table.  Please use the following
'@'Entity
'@'Table(name="comment")

Now since you dropped the schema and re-run the application, it's not possible that the schema is being generated also with this "blog_post_comment" table unless you have defined it in another class.

Comment: Yes please be careful with the different ddl property such as create, it literally drops your db to regenerate it. It's not recommended to use create in prod db

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that Hibernate creates a `blog_post_comment` table after you renamed the entity. I suspect this is just still around from the previous run.

Hibernate (or any other JPA implementation) does not know about you renaming the entity. It has no knowledge what so ever about the entities present during the last start of the application. Therefore it doesn't know that there is a relationship between the existing `blog_post_comment` table in the database and the not yet present `comment` table it is about to create.

When Hibernate "updates" a schema it checks if a required table already exists and if so it modifies it to match what is required by the entities. But even then it won't rename columns, it would just create new ones.

In generally you should use Hibernates schema creation feature only during development and never for actually deploying a schema into production or even worse, updating a schema in production. For this you should use specialised tools like `Flyway` or `Liquibase` which exist for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I've tried changing `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in application.properties from `update` to `create` and `create-drop`, still no go. And I've manually dropped all the tables and rerun the application, the "blog_post_comment" table got created again. But the best practices are really helpful, much appreciated.